# Обратится ко второй БД

Tags: php, база-данных, битрикс

У меня на хостинге 2 базы данных, с одной работает сайт (БД1), в другую выгружаются кое-какие данные (БД2) , которые нужно обновлять на сайте. Как мне подключится к (БД2) и взять оттуда данные? Сайт на битриксе, пробую так, но всё пусто, то есть не соединяет с базой. Может средствами php, без API Битрикса это можно сделать как-то?

```
   <?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");?>
    <?
    $DBHost = "localhost";
    $DBName = "111";
    $DBLogin = "111";
    $DBPassword = "111";
    if(!($DB->Connect($DBHost, $DBName, $DBLogin, $DBPassword)))
    {
       $results = $DB->Query("SELECT `name` FROM `cities`");
       var_dump($results);

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не могу согласиться с принятым решением.
Нужно просто создать новый экземпляр объекта `CDatabase`

```
<?php require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");?>
    <?php
    $DBnew = new CDatabase();
    $DBHost = "localhost";
    $DBName = "111";
    $DBLogin = "111";
    $DBPassword = "111";
    if(!($DBnew->Connect($DBHost, $DBName, $DBLogin, $DBPassword)))
    {
       $results = $DBnew->Query("SELECT `name` FROM `cities`");
       var_dump($results);

    }

?>
```

Таким образом, во-первых, будет собираться статистика по SQL-запросам, а во-вторых, не придется держать в голове особенности обращений с `mysql_query`, которое, к тому же, "[устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет удалено в будущем](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php)".

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример подключения двух БД:

```
$dbOne = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db1);
$dbTwo = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db2);
```

Вот пример выборки из первой БД:

```
$dbOne->query("select * from tablename");
```

Вот пример выборки из второй БД:

```
$dbTwo->query("select * from tablename");
```

Удачного кодинга...

Comment: Спасибо, так получилось, через битрикс видимо даёт работу только с одной бд

Comment: Это решение, которое перестанет работать с одним из будущих обновлений php (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: Функции mysql_* являются устаревшими. Использовать их в "новом коде" является дурным тоном.

Comment: Спасибо за замечания. Обновил.